# This example seems to break the type sig for $, and it works

Tags: haskell, types, dictionary, apply

If the type for `($)` is `(a -> b) -> a -> b`, then why are you allowed to curry it as `($2)`? 
2 is not of type `(a -> b)`.
See below example.

```
map ($2)[(+1),(+2)]
```

This is legit, awesome and intuitively makes sense. Please tell me how it is consistent with the type system rules?

Cheers

Comment: This seems very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17530013/712548) from earlier today.

Comment: eek, didn't notice. It's pretty much exactly the same question. Most embarrasing SO post yet :3 voting to close

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is due to how partial application works for infix operators.  This is often called "section application" and you are applying `2` as the "right section" which would be the second argument.  So you have:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
                   ^
                   |
                  This is the type variable for the argument '2'
```

And you can confirm this via:

```
ghci
> :t ($2)
($2) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

You can likely find this info hidden somewhere in most decently complete tutorials or you can see the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sections) section on sections.

Comment: Also see the possibly more accessible wiki page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator